# Even width between inline elements

Tags: css

I have three inline elements (lets call them squares) which are centered inside the parent div. What i would like to do is align first square to the left of the parent, second square to the center and the third square to the right. In other words, create equal inner margins between squares.

Do not forget that inline-block already adds some margin to the elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="five">

<div>
</div>

<div>
</div>

<div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#five {

    text-align:center;
    width:1110px;
}

#five > div {

    width:340px;
    background-color:red;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Created a fiddle for your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd8LD/

Comment: Its cool, but i want left and right square to be aligned with the borders of the parent element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a span, with the styles:

```
#five > span {    
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

Then change the `text-align` for `#five` to `justify`:

```
#five {
    text-align:justify;
    width:1110px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeuc4/)

Comment: nice I forgot you could justify `inline-block` elements

Comment: Fantastic! The ghostly last element occupying 100% width, forcing a return and therefore a complete previous line, is quite ingenious. @Pete I might point out that you don't actually need to add an extra span — [using the container's `:after` pseudo-element will do the trick fine](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/7TfMQ/).

Comment: @Barney, I've not said anything about a span?

Comment: @Pete the answer above (which you marked as accepted) involves using a span to achieve the effect you asked for. It's right there in the first line of code in the solution: `#five > span`. I'm proposing a tweak of the solution that doesn't involve extra markup.

Comment: @Barney I didn't ask for it, I just commented it was a nice solution

Comment: @Pete yes, I know — I'm not accusing you of anything! I'm just letting you know there's another way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with this:

```
<div id="five">
 <div id="left">
 </div>

 <div>
 </div>

 <div id="right">
 </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
#five {
 text-align:center;
 width:800px;
}

 #five > div {
  width:140px;
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
 }
 #left{
  float: left;
 }
#right{
 float: right;
}
```

This way, it will align left `div` to left, right `div` to right.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bUvu6/2/)